# How to sort list of string based on the second segment of each string?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings that I want to sort in a descending order based on the numbers in the string, and the strings that don't have a number should come first.

```
["dakdmwk 2", "fwewk 1", "fmewkfmwek 4", "oopap 3", "fekamkdflew fnewjke"]
```

Comment: What had you tried so far? seems like sort on 2nd element of splited by space value should work

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Have you looked up how to perform custom sort logic in C#?  Have you written that sort logic?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `OrderByDescending` with following way:

```
list = list
   .OrderByDescending(s => 
    { 
       var arr = s.Split(); 
       if(int.TryParse(arr.Last(),out int i))
           return i;
       return int.MaxValue;
    }).ToList();
```